# Cpu Type vs Cpu clock

Tags: cpu, clockspeed

I have 2 laptops and 1 is older cpu but higher clock rate and another one is more modern cpu but lower clock 
so which one would generally have a better performance?

first laptop: Celeron 2.16 Ghz while
second laptop:Intel I3 1.88 Ghz
Both 4 cpu cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you *do* when you're on your computer:

**More cores, slower clock speed**

**Pros**

- Applications that support multi-threading will greatly benefit from
  having a higher number of cores at their disposal
- Increasing the number of cores in your CPU is a cost-effective way of increasing performance
- Multi-threading support for applications will continue to improve over time
- You will be able to run more apps at once without seeing performance drops
- Great for running multiple virtual machines

**Cons**

- Lower single-threaded performance than a higher clock speed processor

**Fewer cores, higher clock speed**

**Pros**

- Better single threaded performance
- Lower cost option

**Cons**

- Fewer cores to split between applications
- Not as strong multi-threading performance

**Ratings on CPUBENCHMARK:**

- Celeron 2.16 Ghz = [951](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel%20Celeron%20N2830%20%40%202.16GHz&id=2213)
- Intel I3 1.88 Ghz = ??? (need model number)

**TL:DR**

There are other factors that go into this to be compared such as cache, bus speed etc. I would compare the 2 benchmarks on https://www.cpubenchmark.net and see which comes out the victor.

Comment: The second laptop will be much faster, despite its slower clock. It can do more per clock, and most non-trivial programs will take advantage of multiple cores.